# XPerf and Classic ETW Providers

Tags: etw, xperf

Is it possible to collection traces from classic ETW providers? Or is XPerf limited to manifest-based ones? I have a custom classic provider and was wondering if I could collect its event using XPerf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect traces from any ETW provider.

Comment: Do you know how to enable the provider using XPerf? I'm not seeing anything in my logs.

Comment: At least, you can create an `.etl` logfile using `logman` and open it in `xperf`.